# SSH to same directory on remote as local

Tags: ssh

I am trying to write a small function in my `.bashrc` on my dev server that will give me a red shell on our production server that opens in the same location as I am in on the dev server. The `bash` shell starts and is red, but I always start in my home directory.

```
function here-live  {                                                                                                                                                                      
       wd=`pwd -P`                                                                                                                                                                        
       ssh -t server@example.com 'cd $wd ; export PS1="\e[0;31m[\u@\h \W]\$ \e[m " ; bash'                                                                      
}
```

How do I navigate to the same path on the remote machine as I am on the current machine automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your technique is OK, but you're using single quotes, so your `$wd` variable is not being expanded.

Try this:

```
function here-live  {                                                                                                                                                                      
       wd=`pwd -P`                                                                                                                                                                        
       ssh -t server@example.com "cd $wd ;"' export PS1="\e[0;31m[\u@\h \W]\$ \e[m " ; bash'                                                                      
}
```

I only changed the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Basically was a problem with `'` and `"`, this should work :

```
function here-live  {
       wd=`pwd -P`
       ssh -t server@example.com "cd $wd; export PS1='\e[0;31m[\u@\h \W]\$ \e[m '; bash"
}
```